# pyspark: Passing RDD as parameter to a Class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Could you help to retrieve value from a row that is passed as a parameter to a class constructor (or) please suggest a better approach. My aim is to validate the value of all fields. Each field has a different validation criteria.

This is what I am doing:

I have read the hive table using HiveContext and saved in a dataframe. I converted this dataframe to RDD. I am passing each row of the RDD to a class constructor.

```
class Normalizer():
    def __init__(self,val):
        logging.info("Normalizer start...%s"%val)
```

val(in console) looks like :

> [Row(id=u'12', col1=u'xx', col2=u'yy',...)]

I have written a parse method for each field in Normalizer.
Now I have to pass each field value to the corresponding method and validate the data.

How do you get each value of the field? `val.id` does not work.

Or please suggest if you have better approach.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

- It looks like your row is inside a list :

  ```
   val[0].id
  ```
- Why not use a function here ? You can insert a boolean and filter out the wrong rows

  ```
  def normalize(row):
      .... validate row.id ...
      return Row(validated = is_validated, id=row.id)

  myrdd.map(normalize)
  ```

Comment: To your first bullet point, the reason the row is inside a list is probably because she used `take()` or `collect`. If she's accessing it via a map statement, it wouldn't be in a lit. And your 2nd bullet looks like the approach to take

Comment: Thank you. I have taken the second approach.